# JavaScript getelementbyid problem

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, browser-security, blocked

When we use getelementbyid in JS the browser ask to allow or block the script, is there a piece of script to automatically allow that or avoid that or is there an alternative for that

Comment: How does your script look like? And by the way: it’s `getElementById` and not `getelementbyid`.

Comment: I am just guessing here, but this sounds like an alert that says the page has errors and prompts you to stop or continue. If I am write best solution would be to fix the script by showing your code here. :)

Comment: This question really needs more detail.

Comment: @King: Why don’t you just provide us the code that causes this error? You probably just got down voted because you didn’t do it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "the browser" is IE and you are viewing the file locally, this is because IE blocks JavaScript by default in local HTML as a security measure.

If "the browser" is Firefox (very unlikely), this is because `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege` was called. Never call that function.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt that `document.getElementById("id")` will be blocked in a browser. It must be something else causing this.

Comment: i was trying to get ID of a text box and change its attributes

Answer (score 1):

presumably this is the ActiveX alert in IE? Can you confirm exactly what error in what browser and what code you are using - even a snippet should help